# Is there a way to use EcmaScript 6 in SWT-Browser-View under Windows 10?

Tags: java, ecmascript-6, swt, rcp

I write a RCP application with swt-web-view. I get errors when i try to use EcmaScript 6 Scripts. I found out, that swt uses the IE 11 as default and this browser doesnt sopport ES6. Is there a workaround solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093905/). First you have to set the browser to microsoft edge by setting the property

#### -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=12001 in eclipse.ini

in the eclipse.ini file.

After that use an HTML5 doctype and add a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` element to the `<head>` section to use ecmascript 6